# Can't create empty file via python script running through VirtualBox cmd

Tags: python, command-line, virtualbox, permission-denied

I have a simple python script that doing nothing but empty file creation:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open("empty_file.txt", "a"):
        pass
```

Now I just try to run it in virtual machine via VirtualBox cmd like this:

```
VBoxManage guestcontrol "Win10_64" --username admin run --exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\python.exe" -- "-c" -- "F:\empty_file_creation.py"
```

And get an error as below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\empty_file_creation.py", line 3, in <module>
    with open("empty_file.txt", "a"):
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'empty_file.txt'Traceback (most recent call last):
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: use `a+` for opening mode

Comment: tried "a+" and got the same error

Comment: If I run the script in virtual machine manually then everything is ok. The problem arises when I use VirtualBox through cmd.

Comment: What happens when you run as admin with cmd?

Comment: still get an error when run as admin